# QML: Material design not found

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to get Material design as explained in https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-styles.html, when i start app with `-style material`, i get an error :

```
QApplication: invalid style override passed, ignoring it.
    Available styles: Windows, Fusion
```

I checked `/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/` and there is no Material in this. I custom compile QT. But I have official build as well and same result with that.

Comment: On what Qt version/OS did you run it? Btw, on my Linux/5.15 I get the warning `QApplication: invalid style override 'material' passed, ignoring it.
 Available styles: Windows, Fusion`

Comment: it is Qt5.12.6 and Linux/Ubuntu 20.1 or any Linux distribution. Same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build QT with OpenGL. Issue was that Material Design requires some OpenGL libs. But still on deploy few items like Button are not loaded correctly.